# Where to place BroadcastReceiver in an app with several Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app, on which I have several Activities and I must register a `BroadcastReceiver` which should detect, whether we are connected (WiFi/Mobile) or not, I can do that without problems if I do it for a Test Activity but I'm not sure, how I should proceed now in such a Schema

SplashActivity->LoginActivity->MainActivity*

LoginActivity and MainActivity have operations, which need `Connectivity`, my Questions are

**1) Must I register/unregister BroadcastReceiver for LoginActivity and MainActivity separate or is it enough if I register it in LoginActivity and I unregister when I exit from MainActivity(Exit from App)**

**2)** `RegisterReceiver`/`UnregisterReceiver` operations are typically implemented in `onResume`/`onPause` but my `Connectivity` sensible Operations in LoginActivity and MainActivity access to this Data in `onCreate`, therefore, sooner than `onResume` **how could I overcome that.**

*p.s. According to this `Connectivity`, and therefore, response of my Connectivity-`BroadcastReceiver`, I'll be able to go to MainActivity or not.

Edit:
I also get the Dialog with each message(Mobile/WiFi/No Internet) many times

My Code

In my Map Activity looks like this

```
...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

    registerNetworkReceiver();


}

private void registerNetworkReceiver() {

    if (networkChangeReceiver!= null) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, filter);
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (networkChangeReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(networkChangeReceiver);

}
...
```

My BroadcastReceiver

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean firstCheckingConnection = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        NetworkUtils netUtils = new NetworkUtils(context);


        // Avoid multiple callings
        NetworkInfo netInfo = netUtils.getNetworkInfo();

        if ( netInfo != null) {
            if ( firstCheckingConnection ) {
                firstCheckingConnection = false;
                String statusString       = netUtils.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

                // Just Activities can show Dialogs/Windows, so, we must bridge with a dummy Activity!!!
                Intent ad_activity_intent = new Intent(context, AlertDialogActivity.class);

                ad_activity_intent.putExtra(Constants.DESCRIPTION, statusString);   
                ad_activity_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                context.startActivity(ad_activity_intent);
            } else {
                firstCheckingConnection = true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

NetworkUtils Class

```
public class NetworkUtils {

    private static String ssid;
    private static NetworkInfo activeNetwork ;
    private Context context;
    private ConnectivityManager cm;

    public static final int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;



    public NetworkUtils(Context context){
        this.context  = context;
        cm            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ssid                      = "";
        int status                = TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;



        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                status = TYPE_WIFI;

                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiConnectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();  
                if (wifiConnectionInfo != null && !isBlank(wifiConnectionInfo.getSSID())) 
                    ssid   = wifiConnectionInfo.getSSID();

                } else if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    status = TYPE_MOBILE;
            } 

        return status;
    }   

    private static boolean isBlank(String ssid) {
        return ( ssid == null || ssid.length()==0 );
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = "";
        switch (conn) {
            case TYPE_WIFI: 
                status = "Wifi enabled:["+ssid+"]";
            break;
            case TYPE_MOBILE:
                status = "Mobile data enabled";
            break;
            case TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED: 
                status = "Not connected to Internet";
            break;
        }

        return status;
    }   



    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo() {
        return activeNetwork;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I didn't know it, sorry. I won't do it anymore.

Comment: Learning _why_ not to do it is better than any apology.

Comment: post the code you are using to register your `BroadcastReceiver`